# ECDH VS. DH benchmarking in JAVA

Tags: diffie-hellman, key-exchange

So basically my problem is the odd result i get when measuring the time it takes to generate a ECDH key in java vs. the time it takes to generate a DH key.

I compare the time it takes to generate:

- 192bit ECDH-key to a 512bit DH-key
- 224bit ECDH-key to a 1024 DH-key

Now I expected the ECDH key pair generation to beat regular DH keys due to difference in key size, however that is not the case when I do it. Perhaps I'm measuring this wrong or is there another explanation.

```
    public void generateKeyPair() {

    try {

        keyfactory = KeyFactory.getInstance("ECDH");

        keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("ECDH", "BC");

        //NIST EC-Curve P-224"
        org.bouncycastle.jce.spec.ECParameterSpec ecSpec = ECNamedCurveTable.getParameterSpec(EllipticCurveDiffieHellman.curveNames.get(new Integer(224)));

        keyPairGenerator.initialize(ecSpec, new SecureRandom());

    int num = 10;

        /* Warm up */
        for (int wRound = 0; wRound < 200; wRound++) {
            keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair(); 
        }

        /*
         * Finding the right number of iterations such that we iterate for
         * at least 2s
         */
        for (;;) {

            long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();

            for (int i = 0; i < num; i++) {

                keypair = keyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair();
            }

            long end = System.currentTimeMillis();

            long time = end - begin;

            if (time >= 2000) {
                System.out.printf("Average keygen time: %.2f ms\n",
                        (double) time / num);
                break;
            }

            num *= 2;
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry but none of us know how to program, at least that is the assumption you should be going with when posting on Crypto SE. It is likely questions with large amounts of code are better suited on StackOverflow or Security SE, and it is the case here. That said, I suppose the time difference is due to the fact that generating an ECDH key isn't as easy as selecting a random prime, you need to perform some setup operations, likely more than in DH (or maybe your KeyPairGenerator is slow, but that's out of our control).

Comment: Generating a keypair is simply a scalar multiplication for ECDH and a modular exponentiation for DH, both with fixed base point (allows some speedup if the implementation takes advantage of that). | @Thomas You don't need to select a random prime for either of them. Selecting prime is part of group generation, not of keypair generation.

Comment: Which curves are you using for ECDH? Fast ECC implementations need to be optimized for the specific curve you're working on. Perhaps the curves you're working on aren't well optimized in your ECC library.

Comment: @CodesInChaos Thanks for the correction, not very literate in ECC. Still, I think the question should be rewritten to ask for theoretical differences in performance (based on the algorithms themselves and not a black-box implementation) to be on topic.

Comment: You should generate many keypairs (such as 1000 or 10k) in a loop. Else startup code, JIT cost etc. might dominate the actual generation cost. You also forgot to describe your performance results. How fast are your four measurements?

Comment: @CodesInChaos I begin with generating 1000 keypairs (calibration you could say), then I generate an additional 50 pairs which are the ones being measured.

Comment: For ECDH(224) i get (just a sample): 7,8,7,8,7,8,12,8 (ms)
For DH(1024) i get (just a sample): 2,3,3,3,2,3,2,3,3 (ms)

Comment: I assume that the standard library in java has some predefined curves for certain keysizes. Although Im having a hard time figuring them out.

Comment: hmm one thing I didn't think of is that some DH implementations might choose a private key much smaller than the prime size. That would give a significant speedup for keygen but not for keyexchange.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I looked it up. (For DH 1024) 
Public Keysize: 426
Private keysize: 362
Prime size: 1024

Comment: You could compare with BouncyCastle's performance.

Comment: Its the same story there to im afraid..i must be doing something really really stupid..

Comment: @Nyfiken My guess is that you were using the BC implementation for your benchmarks. JDK 7.0 is still fairly fresh and versions previous don't have an EC implementation. At least that's what it looks like from my tests (see my answer). I get the same values for BC as you say you're getting for both straight java an BC.  When I use the JDK 7.0 crypto implementation, EC is faster than DH as expected.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generating an (EC)DH key pair entails "producing" the group parameters (the curve or the modulus+generator), then the private key $x$, (a random integer modulo the group order $q$), and then applying the private key to the generator (i.e. computing $xG$ on the curve, $g^x \mod p$ for plain DH). Producing new group parameters would be the most expensive operation, especially for elliptic curves; however, there is no security issue in reusing the same group parameters for several key pairs.

Most ECDH implementation focus on a handful of standard curves (a subset of the [15 FIPS curves](http://csrc.nist.gov/publications/fips/fips186-3/fips_186-3.pdf)) and never generate new ones. Generating new group parameters for DH is quite easier, but still expensive, which is why some implementations just reuse a few pre-generated parameters. Thus, the remaining operations for (EC)DH key pair generation are fast; we are in the milliseconds range.

---

Your code for measuring generation time fails to take into account the idiosyncrasies of Java. The first time an application accesses a class, it must *load* that class, which entails locating it in the Jar archives, reading it from disk, uncompressing it, decoding the class file format, and launching the initialization code for that class, which may do a lot of expensive things. Then, for each *method*, the first call to the method triggers the *verification* which is a flow analysis by which the JVM makes sure that the code complies to the Java typing rules. Finally, the first few invocations of the method will use *interpretation*; only methods which are invoked sufficiently many times will be translated to efficient native code (this is known as "JIT compilation").

All this translates to the following: to benchmark Java code, you must allow for some considerable "warm up". Also, you will want to run the code several times in a loop so as to get an *average* execution time because any single invocation can be substantially delayed in case, for instance, of a garbage collector run (the JVM aims at *perceived* smooth execution, but human beings do not perceive hiccups below about 20ms). So your benchmark code should look like this:

```
/* warm-up */
for (int i = 0; i < 200; i ++) {
    generateKeyPair();
}

/* find the right number of loop iterations such that we loop for at
   least two seconds */
int num = 10;
for (;;) {
    long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();
    for (int i = 0; i < num; i ++) {
        generateKeyPair();
    }
    long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long time = end - begin;
    if (time >= 2000) {
        System.out.printf("average keygen time: %.2f ms",
            (double)time / num);
        System.out.println();
        break;
    }
    num *= 2;
}
```

Comment: Cheers Thomas!:) This was indeed enlightning.

Comment: I find this really strange, ECDH (224bit) keygen takes approx: ~7ms while DH (1024bit) takes approx: ~3 ms. Now, i would expect that java's standard security lib uses some (as Thomas mentioned) predefined curves for respective keysizes. Even though finding any info regarding this seems impossible.

Comment: What's strange is that my own EC code, written in pure Java, takes about 1 ms for such an operation, on the NIST P-224 curve. This might be a case of sloppy coding, which is surprising since Sun themselves wrote the EC code for OpenSSL, and they invented Java, so chances are that they know what they are doing.

Comment: I might be doing something wrong, and if so im dont have the slightest clue to what it is. I find it unlikely that th Sun library is the problem. Just for the sake of it i poste the revised code again.

Answer (score 3):

I made sure I used the java (Sun) implementation in Java 7 and tried these different generators:

EC:

```
keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
ECGenParameterSpec spec = new ECGenParameterSpec("secp224r1");
keyPairGenerator.initialize(spec, new SecureRandom());
```

DH:

```
keyPairGenerator = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("DH");
keyPairGenerator.initialize(1024, new SecureRandom());
```

These give me results:

EC: 0.83ms (constantly the same value)
DH: 2.00ms (this fluctuates by max 0.1 ms for each run)

That makes EC more than twice as fast as Diffe-Hellman.

For fun I clocked RSA, which took $\approx$58 ms.

Using BC with the same parameters, I get 6-7 ms for EC, and around 3ms for DH.

This should prove that the issue lies with the bouncy castle implementation.

EDIT:

I should mention that I use JDK 7.0, since 6.0 and earlier don't ship with a built-in EC implementation.

Comment: BC uses affine coordinates (at least the implementation I looked at, perhaps it offers multiple), which are *really* slow for most curves. Optimized implementations should be 10-20 times as fast as BC.

Comment: FWIW, NIST rates ECC-224 as similar strength of DH-**2048**, and other authorities (excluding the oldest) at www.keylength.com range up to **3154**, which presumably further increases the ECC advantage.

Comment: Java is a bad language for crypto, since it does not give access to machine-dependent features like SIMD.  Better to call out to native code by JNI (but OpenJDK does not do this for some reason).

Comment: @Demi That depends, many BigInteger operations will use intrinsics in Java 9, giving you (most of) the memory/type protection of Java and reasonably fast crypto. Yes, native code will be even faster, but do you want to trade in security to drop below 1/2 ms running time for an expensive operation that's usually performed only a few times per connection (being generous I include certificate validation)?